# How to add a custom button on toolbar in kendo RichTextEditor for REACT

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

I want to add a custom button on toolbar that executes custom function in kendo RichTextEditor for REACT

I need to open a modalbox while clicking an icon on edior tool bar,
i can achive this in kendo ui for jquery

```
   $("#editor").kendoEditor({
           tools: [{
                name: "Custom Modal Popup",
                tooltip: "Show data in popup",
                exec: function(e) {
                    console.log('my custom function');
                    console.log('code to open modalbox and view content in it');
                }
            }]
   })
```

but how do i achive this in kendo react ?

```
<Editor tools={[ [ MyColorTool, MyCustomButtonForModalPopup] ]} contentStyle={{ height: 320 }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by making a custom tool.

```
const createInsertTool = settings =>
props => {
    const { view } = props;
    const nodeType = view && view.state.schema.nodes[settings.nodeType];
    const canInsert = view && EditorUtils.canInsert(view.state, nodeType);
    return (
        <Button
            onClick={() => EditorUtils.insertNode(view, nodeType.createAndFill(settings.attrs))}
            disabled={!canInsert}
            onMouseDown={e => e.preventDefault()}
            onPointerDown={e => e.preventDefault()}
            {...settings.props}
        />
    );
};
```

There are examples in the documentation for it:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/editor/tools/#toc-using-custom-tools

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like a Popper or Portal, you can create a custom component that consists of just a button, and then opens the desired popup on click. In my tool, all I pass in to the component is the view of the editor, and then run `EditorUtils.applyInlineStyle(view, {style: ...})`

For Example, here's a color picker tool I use in my kendo editor:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { EditorUtils } from "@progress/kendo-react-editor";
import ColorPicker from "../ColorSwatchButton/ColorSwatchButton";

const ColorTool = props => {
  const [toolColor, setToolColor] = useState({
    rgb: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0.5 },
  });

  const { view } = props;

  const handleColorChange = (color, event) => {
    setToolColor(color);
    EditorUtils.applyInlineStyle(view, { style: "color", value: color.hex });
  };

  return <ColorPicker color={toolColor} colorChangeFn={handleColorChange} isKendo/>;
};

export default ColorTool;
```

Where `<ColorPicker>` is the button that opens a modal that I mentioned before.

After that, you can just pass `ColorPicker` in with the other buttons that you pass in to the `tools` prop of `<Editor>`